# Autogrowing TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, rte

Is there a way to have autogrowing TinyMCE editors? I want the height of the editor to depent on the content and to grow while typing.

I tried some solutions I found while googling, but none of them worked.

I'm using the jQuery version of TinyMCE

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this plugin:

http://www.springload.co.nz/love-the-web/tinymce-plugin-release-auto-resize/

TinyMCE already has an auto-resize experimental feature, they fixed it and released the fix as a plugin. Nothing else to say about this, let us know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [autoresize tinymce plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3aautoresize)